# @RequestParam in GET is always null when it's called using HTTPs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this method right now:

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/api2/rep/report_payment_grouped/{startDate}/{endDate}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity getPaymentsGroupedReport(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        @PathVariable String startDate,
                                        @PathVariable String endDate,
                                        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "requestId") Integer requestId) {
```

This returns an object Report with two list, fieldsDefs, data, and the requestId received in the original request:

```
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok(new Report(fieldDefs, data, requestId));
```

This is the returned object client side(it's correct):

[image]

In the network data:

[image: report_payment_grouped]

Now, the exact same request when the service is deployed in my AWS server, requestId is always null:

[image]

This is the response:

[image]

I have tried manually setting the requestId serverSide and the value is returned correctly in that case. So it's confirmed that requestId parameter is being received as null/empty.

Comment: Trying to get parameter via `request.getParameter("requestId");` or showing the code how you pass the parammeter in client.

Comment: Can you provide code for new Report constructor?

Comment: Is this "AWS server" an EC2 machine? And are you accessing it directly or, are you going through some other AWS service such as CloudFront?

Comment: Please describe what is between your browser and the application. What kind of http proxy are you using, what kind of load balancer is there, any zuul or other api gateway?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your service on AWS isn't able to access the database. Have you looked at the error logs?

Comment: The information is there. data and fieldDefs have the correct information. just requestId is being received null.

Comment: what annotation do you have on `requestId`?